# R: data.table vs merge(aggregate()) performance

Tags: r, data.table

Or to be more general, it's `DT[,.SD[...],by=...]` versus `merge(aggregate(...))`.

Without further ado, here's data and example:

```
set.seed(5141)
size = 1e6
df <- data.table(a = rnorm(size),
                 b = paste0(sample(letters, size, T), 
                            sample(letters, size, T), 
                            sample(letters, size, T)),
                 c = sample(1:(size/10), size, T),
                 d = sample(seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), 
                                     as.Date("2015-05-31"), by="day"), size, T))

system.time(df[,.SD[d == max(d)], by = c])
# user  system elapsed 
# 50.89    0.00   51.00 
system.time(merge(aggregate(d ~ c, data = df, max), df))
# user  system elapsed 
# 18.24    0.20   18.45
```

Usually having no problem with `data.table` performance, I got surprised by this particular example. I had to subset (aggregate) a fairly large data frame by taking only latest (can be simultaneous) occurrences of some event types. And keep the rest of relevant data for those particular events. However, it seems that `.SD` doesn't scale well in this particular application.

Is there a better "data table way" to tackle this kind of tasks?

Comment: Interestingly, `df[,is_max:=d==max(d), by = c][is_max==T,]` runs very fast on my machine.

Comment: This seems to be the fastest solution so far. Would it be possible to do the same thing without creating the extra column?

Comment: I don't know, you could always delete it afterwards `df[,is_max:=d==max(d), by = c][is_max==T,][, is_max:=NULL,]`. And the join-solution provided by @Akrun is by far the fastest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `.I` to get the row index and subset the rows based on that. It should be faster.

```
system.time(df[df[,.I[d == max(d)], by = c]$V1])
#    user  system elapsed 
#   5.00    0.09    5.30
```

@Heroka's solution

```
system.time(df[,is_max:=d==max(d), by = c][is_max==T,])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  5.06    0.00    5.12
```

The `aggregate` method on my machine gives

```
system.time(merge(aggregate(d ~ c, data = df, max), df))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  48.62    1.00   50.76
```

with the `.SD` option

```
system.time(df[,.SD[d == max(d)], by = c])
#   user  system elapsed 
# 151.13    0.40  156.57
```

Using the `data.table` join

```
system.time(df[df[, list(d=max(d)) , c], on=c('c', 'd')])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.58    0.01    0.60
```

---

If we look at the comparisons between the `merge/aggregate` and the `==`, they are different functions.  Usually, the `aggregate/merge` method will be slower when compared to the coresponding join with `data.table`.  But, instead we are using `==` that compares every row (takes some time) along with `.SD` for subsetting (which also is relatively less efficient when compared to `.I` for row indexing).  The `.SD` also has the overhead of `[.data.table`.

Comment: I think that join solution is missing something. And suspiciously good result. Meanwhile, I'll look into `.I` solution. Thanks for providing whole array to try.

Comment: @A.Val.  If you look at the syntax, i am using `on`.  You can test the solution on a smaller dataset

Comment: `> nrow(df[df[, list(d=max(d)) , c], on='c'])
[1] 1000000`

Comment: @A.Val.  Thanks for the info, I will look into it,

Comment: @A.Val.  Try with `on= c('c', 'd')`  It gives the same nrow as the other results.