# Remove duplicates from dataset based on criteria

Tags: r

I have a dataset of scores:

```
    ID      Sub     Score
    1       Mat     45
    2       Mat     34
    3       Mat     67
    1       Mat     43
    2       Mat     34
    4       Mat     22
    5       Sci     78
    6       Mat     32
    1       Mat     56
    1       Sci     40
```

I want to output only the top scores for each ID in each subject. For example, the new list should show:

```
    ID      Sub     Score
    2       Mat     34
    3       Mat     67
    4       Mat     22
    5       Sci     78
    6       Mat     32
    1       Mat     56
    1       Sci     40
```

I can find the duplicated results through:

```
results[duplicated(results[, c(1,2)]),]
```

How to order the results and delete the lowest scoring ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to get the expected output.  One option with `dplyr` would be to group by 'ID', 'Sub' columns, get the top Score observation with `top_n`, and if there are duplicate rows, use `distinct`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID, Sub) %>%
  top_n(1) %>% 
  distinct()
  ID   Sub Score
#   (int) (chr) (int)
#1     2   Mat    34
#2     3   Mat    67
#3     4   Mat    22
#4     5   Sci    78
#5     6   Mat    32
#6     1   Mat    56
#7     1   Sci    40
```

---

Or with `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', 'Sub', we `order` the 'Score' in descending and subset the first row of each group combination (`.SD[1L]` or `head(.SD, 1)` can be used).

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(df1)[order(-Score), .SD[1L] ,.(ID, Sub)]
```

Or another option is `unique` after we `order` by the columns so that it will only select the first observation for each duplicate.

```
unique(setDT(df1)[order(ID, Sub,-Score)], by = c('ID', 'Sub'))
```

---

Or with `base R`, we `order` the columns, and use `duplicated` to remove the rows that are duplicates for the first two columns.

```
df2 <- df1[with(df1, order(ID, Sub, -Score)),]
df2[!duplicated(df2[1:2]),]
```

Comment: Hmm. I wonder whether `.SD[1L]` or `unique` is faster, given `.SD[1L]` was recently optimized IIRC

Comment: @MichaelChirico  In a recent benchmark [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223311/r-data-table-vs-mergeaggregate-performance/35223362#35223362), I find `.SD` to be very slow (but I did that using 1.9.6.  It might have changed altogether in the devel version).  To my knowledge, `unique` is fast.  It would be good to have some benchmarks with the devel version.

Comment: Yea, this was done somewhat recently, Arun has been doing a lot of work on GForce optimizing of late; I think [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/751baff13114fb8dff972662cde11fec10d0f16e) is the commit that makes me think `.SD[1L]` could be competitive

Answer (score 3):

Or `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Score ~ ID + Sub, df, max)

#ID Sub Score
#1  1 Mat    56
#2  2 Mat    34
#3  3 Mat    67
#4  4 Mat    22
#5  6 Mat    32
#6  1 Sci    40
#7  5 Sci    78
```